# Difference between a ExecutorCompletionService and a FixedThreadPool executor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

As far as I know, executor completion service provides the output from the future object regardless of the order in which the task was requested in the inbound queue, i.e. whichever task is completed first the Result is put into the Outbound Queue. On the other hand, `FixedThreadPool` also executes the tasks parallelly, then what is the difference between the two? ( Not sure whether the `FixedThreadPool` gives the output sequentially in the order the tasks were fed to the inbound queue )

Thanks.

Comment: A fixed thread pool (like most thread pools) will take the tasks from the queue in the order that they were submitted, but the tasks are going to finish whenever they finish. If some tasks take longer than others, then the shorter tasks have a good chance of finishing first. The one interesting case is a fixed thread pool that has exactly one thread: In that case, it can not start the next task until the previous task has finished.

Answer (score 1):

`FixedThreadPool` is one of the variations of `Executor`. It uses class `ThreadPoolExecutor` with same values for `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize`. It means, if you create `FixedThreadPool` with 10 threads, it will always keep exact 10 threads. If any of these threads are terminated by running task - thread pool will create new ones to keep required amount.

> CompletionService arranges that submitted tasks are, upon completion, placed on a queue.

It means, that all results of submitted tasks will be in a queue and you can process them later.
When you submit a task to a `CompletionService`, it creates a wrapper, so the result of async task is saved to queue. It doesn't create parallelism itself, instead `CompletionService` uses inside `Executor` for making parallel threads. You can pass `FixedThreadPool` inside, for example.

All tasks, submitted to `FixedThreadPool` and `CompletionService` will be done in parallel, without keeping the order.

`CompletionService` can be used, when you need to know when all of your tasks are finished. Example:

```
//Task extends Callable<Result>
List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
CompletionService<Result> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
tasks.forEach(task -> cs.submit(task));
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) { // you should know exact amount of submitted tasks
    Result r = cs.take().get();
    //process r
}
```

`FixedThreadPool` can be used in any other case, when you want to parallel threads without waiting for the results.

Also, note the difference between `FixedThreadPool` and `CachedThreadPool`. The first one is usually used when you need to keep threads alive and limit their amount. The seconds one is limited by system, it will process as many threads in parallel as possible. If a thread is in idle state in `CachedThreadPool` it will be automatically deleted after timeout (default is 60 seconds).

Comment: Re, "it will always try to keep exact 10 threads." There is no "try". A call to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` will create ten threads, and it will return an `ExecutorService` that owns those same ten threads. The only way any of those threads will terminate before the service is shut down is if a submitted task kills its own thread. In that case, the service will create a new thread to replace the one that died, and that is the only way that a new thread will ever be created.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes, that is exactly what I meant by `try`. It may be at some time there are less than ten, but the difference will be created by a thread pool. Maybe I should be more clear when typing the answers. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Unable to see the difference if both can be used for parallel execution. what do we achieve  from completion service

Comment: @jayendrabhatt You can treat `CompletionService` as a wrapper around `Executor`, which allows you to get results of all submitted tasks. `Executor` only runs submitted tasks in parallel, it returns you `Future` and you should save it somewhere to get results.